# Javascript - Changing value of select box updates string only once

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, jquery-select2

I have a page where a user has to select 3 things via select options. First the user selects a color, next a word and lastly a number.

```
<select name="color" id="color" size="3">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
<select name="cos" id="cos" size="3">
    <option value="-moon">Moon</option>
    <option value="-star">Star</option>
    <option value="-sun">Sun</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year" size="3">
    <option value="-2000">2000</option>
    <option value="-3000">3000</option>
    <option value="-4000">4000</option>
</select>
<div id="output" class="button"></div>
```

The value's of these options I am using as 'str' for an url, which get outputted in the #output div:

```
var selectedAllLength = $("select").length;
$("select").change(function() {
        var str = location.origin;
        var selected = $("select option:selected");
        var selectedCount = selected.length;
        if (selectedCount == selectedAllLength) {
            selected.each(
                function() {
                    str += $(this).attr('value');
                }
            );
            $("#output").html('<a href=' + str + '>GO!</a>');
        }
    })
    .on('change.select2');
```

If a user chooses the first time, it works. After changing some variables via the select/options, 'str' gets updated to the right values. The only thing that doesn't work is when a user selects something he previously already selected. If he does, 'str' is not updated.

For example, the user chooses Blue, Moon, 2000, 'str' is outputed like `blue-moon-2000`. If the user then switches to Red, Moon, 2000.. 'str' get updated to `red-moon-2000`. So far so good. If he then changes his mind and selects Blue again, 'str' remains `red-moon-2000`.

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this? And how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any error reports?

Comment: Yes, it gives no errors

Answer (score 0):

The JSFiddle can't replicate this issue. The only difference I can imagine is the version of jQuery you're running or else a conflict from some other js file.

https://jsfiddle.net/29Lajogk/

I see nothing wrong with your

```
var selectedAllLength = $("select").length;
$("select").change(function () {
    var str = location.origin;
    var selected = $("select option:selected");
    var selectedCount = selected.length;
    if(selectedCount == selectedAllLength) {
        selected.each(
        function () {
            str += $(this).attr('value');             
        }
        );
        $("#output").html('<a href=' + str + '>GO!</a>');
    }
})
.on('change.select2');
```

Comment: Hm, I actually use images to make the selections.. the actual select boxes are hidden, and clicking the corresponding image sets the right option value. This is also done via javascipt, so I guess the problem lies here..